# What's the technical term for this image animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Does anyone know the technical term for this image https://yelvy.com animation by scrolling (this ghosting)?

Comment: you can use developer tool to check out.

Comment: i was trying but i can't find nothing about this animation :(

Comment: I don't know but it looks more like a bug than a feature :)

Comment: After delete a lot of item (which make my browser slow :(     ), It seems it just put a lot of copy of that image

Comment: it's all under this elememt : `document.querySelector('.stack-scroll-canvas.js-sticky-element')`

Comment: Guess it's called stack scroll?

Comment: So this is actually a img onder img.. thats are delayed

Comment: it's actually 4-imgs under img and delayed use css transform.

Comment: ok thank you @appleapple i gonna try that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is my guess (I would suggest not doing this since it looks pretty like lagged animation)

```js
let imags = [...document.querySelectorAll('.sample.imag')]

let real = document.querySelector('.sample.real')

let x = real.getClientRects()[0].x
let anchor = x

function updatePos(){
  x = real.getClientRects()[0].x;
  anchor = anchor*0.8 + x*0.2;
  if(Math.abs(anchor-x)<1){anchor=x;}
}

setInterval(()=>{updatePos();blend()},200)

function blend(){
  if(anchor==x)return;
  let length = imags.length
  let delta = anchor-x
  let unit = delta/length
  for(let index in imags){
    imags[index].style.transform = `translate(${unit*(length-index+1)}px, 0px)`
  }
}
```

```css
.largearea{
  width:200vw;
  padding-left:100px;  
}
.sample{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:blue;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.real{
  position:relative;
}
.imag{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1
}
```

```html
<div class="largearea">
  <div class="sample real">
    <div class="sample imag"></div>
    <div class="sample imag"></div>
    <div class="sample imag"></div>
    <div class="sample imag"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for help I have made this little bit simpler making 4 layers with each one delayed on scroll. Its working great.

Comment: why the downvote? I just try to mimic the page's animation technic. I think it work well. If you have some thought, I am open to your opinion.